# Bitcoin dont show in my Phantom wallet

Tags: wallet, phantom, bitcoin

Bitcoin dont show in my Phantom wallet and I have no option to activate it?
I have updated all my extensions by going into dev mode on Brave but don't seem to figure out how to enable auto-updates.

Comment: Unrelated question.

Answer (score 1):

For assistance with this, please contact Phantom support directly via your wallet Settings > Help & Support.